# Какими инструментами openCV можно измерить толщину линии? К каким разделам библиотеки это относится?

Tags: python, opencv, изображения

Сейчас изучаю OpenCV на python. Я остановился на контурах, а именно нахождении цифр на белом фоне по каким-то признакам. Сейчас придумал новое задание - распознать самую большую по толщине цифру на изображении.

Все сами по себе цифры я распознать смог, переведя картинку в чб формат с помощью пороговых преобразований. Однако дальше я впал в ступор, так как плохо понимаю, как объяснить программе, что я хочу найти именно по толщине символ а не по размерам или же занимаемой площади. Я рассмотрел разные разделы, а именно: морфологические операции(было сказано, что они связаны с работой с формой объектов, однако потом я понял, что эта работа с формой относится больше к удалению каких-либо неточностей, шумов, неровностей на изображении, оставляя лишь каркас, с которым будет удобнее работать дальше. Это ведь так?), контуры(функции contourArea, arcLength. Однако с ними программа выводила только самую большую или же самую маленькую цифру именно по размерам, а не по толщине), рассчитывать среднее расстояние между соседними точками контура объекта(это будет очень долго и не даст точные и правдивые результаты во многих случаях, например, когда мы рисуем неровную цифру в Paint).

На этом мои представления о том, как эту треклятую толщину рассчитать закончились. Я бы хотел попросить вас по возможности сказать мне, какие разделы в opencv мне именно нужно посмотреть для решения задачи, дав этим некую наводку, а дальше я напишу нормальный алгоритм. Или, если эта задача не относится к OpenCV, то сказать, что вне её мне надо смотреть. И если для этого потребуется какая-то математика, то какая? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если границы символов более-менее ровные, можно попробовать cv::distanceTransform

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081908/how-to-determine-the-width-of-the-lines)